# getMonth() in model of moments

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have a model containing momments like this:
[image]

What I want is to get the month from it. Instead of that array of Momments I want an array of months.

I tried to do it like in the picture using `model.xAxisDates.getMonth()` but it returns `undefined`.

Any ideas how to do it right? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) instead of `getMonth()` to get month number.

`getMonth()` is the private function while [`month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) is the public function exposed in the API.

If you need to get the short month name use [`format('MMM')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

From the `format` tokens docs:

- `MMM`: Jan Feb ... Nov Dec
- `MMMM`: January February ... November December

---

Since `xAxisDates` is an `Array` of moment objects, you can do something like the following:

```js
model.xAxisDates.map( d => d.month() );
```

If you need month short name (e.g. Jan, Feb etc):

```js
model.xAxisDates.map( d => d.format('MMM') );
```

Comment: I changed it and now I get an error saying `Possibly unhanded TypeError: model.xAxisDates.month is not a function`. Isn't it right how I used it?

Comment: @migea sorry I forgot to add parenthesis, `month()` is a function, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I used it with `()`, the problem is that it is `undefined`. http://i.imgur.com/lyFH6kD.png

Comment: @migea `month()` is a moment function, you have to call it on moment objects. What is the type of `xAxisDates`? As a general rule, it is better to share code samples instead of images.

Comment: I tried with arrow functions as you said in your last update. Still doesn't work, `summerIndex = -1, monthLabel = "Sep"`, it doesn't find it

Comment: @migea as I said in the first part of the answer you have to use [`format('MMM')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) if you need short month names.